# Separating multiple JTables

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cardlayout

I'm writing a GUI. In that GUI I have a dropdown box in which I can select different persons. Each person has a CardLayout Pane and in that Pane a table with information about themselves and things they own.

I have written a class called `PanelTableItems(Person person)`.

On program start I use this class to create mutliple of these tables (one for each person in my program). And each CardLayout Pane has one of these tables. I have just implemented a `ListSelectionListener` to store the last selected row which I am using a private function to get the selected item from the table. However as I implemented this selection listener I tried with a print and for some reason it seems that if I have two persons in my program the selection listener made two prints even though the "second" table was not in view and therefore not selected.

## Here is my question:

How do I make sure to only operate the table that is currently in "view" using the CardLayout? The second pane is hidden but it seems that all function calls to the first pane also manages to run on the second one as they are of the same type.

I could post a MCVE, but this is more of a theoretical/solution question than an actual coding question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for me `Each person has a CardLayout Pane and in that Pane a table with information about themselves and things they own.` == JTable with RowFilter instead of  `And each CardLayout Pane has one of these tables.`, because you can to remove column from JTables view, data are still accesible from model, there you can to store bunch of data

Answer (score 3):

On person selection, you could just switch visible panel with:

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
cl.show(cards, "idOfTheSelectedPersonPanel");
```

So, you should have registered those panels already in the layout each one with different id in regard to the person it represents.

Hidden (not visible) panels do not get any user input - if you see such behaving then your code does something wrong.

In ListSelectionListener you need to filter to process only events that something new is selected.

Comment: After considering my code again, I found that what you're saying is right. And yes, it was my ListSelectionListener that made me unsure of what was going on as it seemed to respond for both jtables when something new was selected on the original table. I don't know why however.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to recheck the way you are adding the components to your cards you are maybe adding all tables to the same container witch makes only the last one visible, try adding each table to a JPanel or a JScrollPane.